# Mapbox Text-field Json

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I need to select a point on my map and show the data, but I don't know if it is possible with the interface that Mapbox offers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [queryrenderedfeatures](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#queryrenderedfeatures) . This will return you the features that are displayed in your map style and are at the point where you clicked. You can then do whatever you like with the features under your pointer, e.g. display them.

Please also see this example:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/